# What range should I use for custom error codes in node?

Tags: node.js, meteor, error-handling

I'm using meteor and want to throw an error within a template with a custom error code. What values are already taken, and is this an acceptable way of distinguishing between custom errors? I'm only catching these errors within this template, so creating custom error classes seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if the built in [meteor error](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_error) will meet your needs, but it provides a way to have clearly defined types of errors without the need to make new error classes.

the code could be something like this:

```
const ERROR_TYPE_A = 'error-type-a';

// code...

throw new Meteor.Error(ERROR_TYPE_A, "this can be a human readable string, which could be displayed to the user");
```

in the catching context:

```
if (err.error === ERROR_TYPE_A){
  // switch on type...
}
```

you could then type check the exception against the constant.

hope that helps.